# Converting an array of arrays to list of JSON objects instead of JSON strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I'm trying to convert an array of arrays to a list of JSON objects.

```
var headers = ['first name','last name','age']

var data = [ [ 'John', 'Gill', '21' ], [ 'Sai', 'Varun', '21' ] ]
```

When we use the above two lists to generate a list of JSON's, output will be like,

```
[ { 'First name': 'John', 'Last name': 'Gill', age: '21' },
  { 'First name': 'Sai', 'Last name': 'Varun', age: '21' } ]
```

But I'm in need of the output to be as, (double quoted strings and the JSON should not be a string but should be a JSON object)

```
[ {"First name":"John","Last name":"Gill","age":"21"},
  {"First name":"Sai","Last name":"Varun","age":"21"} ]
```

I tried using `JSON.stringify` but the result won't be a `JSON object` right, it'll be a `JSON string` which would prevent accessing each of the JSON's from the list as a whole.

I have gone through many such answers but in vain. Can someone shed some light on this?!

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried using `JSON.stringify` which I have already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: @GeomanYabes That would eventually return `data` right?!

Answer (score 4):

You could generate an array with the objects first and the stringify the array.

```js
var headers = ['first name', 'last name', 'age'],
    data = [['John', 'Gill', '21'], ['Sai', 'Varun', '21']],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        var object = {};
        headers.forEach(function (k, i) {
            object[k] = a[i];
        });
        return object;
    });
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var headers = ['first name', 'last name', 'age'],
    data = [['John', 'Gill', '21'], ['Sai', 'Varun', '21']],
    result = data.map(a => headers.reduce((r, k, i) => Object.assign(r, { [k]: a[i] }), {}));
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var headers = ['first name','last name','age']
var data = [ [ 'John', 'Gill', '21' ], [ 'Sai', 'Varun', '21' ] ]

function createItem(item) {
    newObject = {}
    item.map((val,i)=>newObject[headers[i]]=val)
 return newObject
}

console.log(data.map(item=>createItem(item)))
```

Comment: Wanted to say Nina's solution is much more elegant, shorter and faster. But was surprised it's a bit (35%) slower after all: https://jsbench.me/u9iziasjz2/1

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var headers = ['first name','last name','age'];

var data = [['John', 'Gill', '21'],['Sai', 'Varun', '21']];

var res = data.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i in headers) {
    obj[headers[i]] = item[i];
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```